Running 1 command with yargs, for some reason it runs all
When I run 1 cli command (contenthook run ) example script: start. Then it doesn't execute any command and in my older version of the code without passing the handler to yargs, it executed all commands at once by the command.run(argv) function. I dont know why and cannot find a valid solution. Please help.
my index.js:
#! /usr/bin/env node
/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
import yargs from "yargs";
import { hideBin } from "yargs/helpers";
import fs from "node:fs";
import path from "node:path";
import { fileURLToPath, pathToFileURL } from "node:url";

import globalConfig from "./configs/global.js";

const colors = globalConfig.colors;
const cliName = globalConfig.cliName;

async function loadCommands() {
  const __dirname = path.dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));
  const commandsDir = path.join(__dirname, "commands");
  const files = await fs.promises.readdir(commandsDir);
  const commandModules = await Promise.all(
    files
      .filter((file) => file.endsWith(".js"))
      .map(async (file) => {
        const commandPath = pathToFileURL(path.join(commandsDir, file));
        return import(commandPath);
      }),
  );
  return commandModules.map((module) => module.default);
}

(async () => {
  try {
    const commands = await loadCommands();

    // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
    const argv = () => yargs(hideBin(process.argv));

    await commands.map((command) => {
      argv().command({
        command: `${cliName.toLowerCase()} ${command.metadata.name}`,
        describe: command.metadata.description,
        handler: (argv)=>{command.run(argv)},
      });
    });

    // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
    yargs(hideBin(process.argv)).argv;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
})();

example command code:
/* eslint-disable no-undef */
import fs from "node:fs";
import path from "node:path";
import globalConfig from "../configs/global.js";

// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
import { spawn } from "child_process";

const metadata = {
  name: "run <command>",
  description: "Execute a command configured in the contenthook config file",
};

// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
const run = async (argv) => {
  const configFiles = fs
    .readdirSync(process.cwd())
    .filter((file) => file.startsWith("contenthook.config"));
  if (configFiles.length === 0) {
    console.log(
      `${globalConfig.colors.yellow}Configuration file already exists at ${path.join(process.cwd(), configFiles[0])}${globalConfig.colors.clear}`,
    );
    return;
  } else if (configFiles.length > 1) {
    console.log(
      `${globalConfig.colors.yellow}Multiple configuration files found. Please delete the wrong one.${globalConfig.colors.clear}`,
    );
    return;
  }

  const configPath = path.join(process.cwd(), configFiles[0]);
  let configModule;
  try {
    configModule = await import(pathToFileURL(configPath));
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error: Failed to import config file.\n${error}`);
    return;
  }

  const config = configModule.default;
  const command = process.argv[process.argv.length - 1];

  const packageJson = require(path.join(process.cwd(), "package.json"));
  const projectName = packageJson.name;
  const projectVersion = packageJson.version;
  const currentDirectoryPath = process.cwd();

  if (!config.scripts || !config.scripts[command]) {
    console.error(
      `Error: No script named "${command}" found in contenthook.config${path.extname(configFiles[0])}.`,
    );
    return;
  }

  const [cmd, ...args] = config.scripts[command].split(" ");

  console.log(
    `\n> ${projectName}@${projectVersion} @contenthook/engine-run ${command} ${currentDirectoryPath}`,
  );
  console.log(`> ${config.scripts[command]}\n\n`);

  const child = spawn(cmd, args);

  child.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
    console.log(`${data}`);
  });

  /*
child.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.error(`stderr: ${data}`);
});
*/

  child.on("error", (error) => {
    console.error(`> @contenthook/engine-run - error: ${error.message}`);
  });

  child.on("close", (code) => {
    console.log(`> @contenthook/engine-run - process exited with code ${code}`);
  });
};

export default {
  metadata,
  run,
};

I tried running my cli (contenthook run start) but for some reason it just returns:
C:\Users\JonasFranke\Documents\test>contenthook run start

C:\Users\JonasFranke\Documents\test>

